# insert statement wont work

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

Hey guys I get no errors from my code but nothing seems to happen when i try my insert statement below?
Not sure if its how I wrapped my textbox or if its my FriendID query string?

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string friendid = Request.QueryString["FriendID"];
        string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
        using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=***; User=***; Password=***;"))
        {
            cn.Open();
            using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO WallPosting (UserID, Wallpostings, FriendUserID) VALUES (" + friendid + ", '" + TextBox1.Text + "', " + theUserId + ")", cn))
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        PopulateWallPosts(friendid);
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll want to fix this _major_ SQL injection vulnerability, for one thing.  _Especially_ if your website is using the `root` user (which it really shouldn't be using).  As it stands, the fact that your database _isn't_ being modified is a stroke of very good luck.

Comment: Maybe do a try...catch and see if you get to the catch block and check ex.message.

Comment: What happens when you debug?  Does `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` get called?  When it does, what's the text of the command?  (Since you're using string concatenation, might as well use it to your advantage for the moment and see the full `INSERT` statement being executed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You switched your variables, according to the field names it should be:

```
using (OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO WallPosting (UserID, Wallpostings, FriendUserID) VALUES (" + theUserId + ", '" + TextBox1.Text + "', " + friendid  + ")", cn))
```

New record **has** been added, but for the wrong user so you didn't find it later when reloading the posts.

As you've been told already deal with the SQL Injection risk by using Parameters instead of directly adding the values to the SQL string.

Comment: hey shadow i switched them for a reason, im working on the friends page so switching them to denote whos wall your posting on based upon the urlencode for my querystring when you click on a friend from your own page

Comment: @Garrith OK, but to see the newly inserted record have `PopulateWallPosts(friendid);` instead. Unless you're using some database explorer and see nothing has been inserted?

Comment: arghhh I found my problem, when i made the duplicate page I copy n pasted the code from my html the buttons where all messed up away to try it now

Comment: yup was a button problem, all fine now! Thanks for your time Shadow

Answer (score 0):

```
"INSERT INTO WallPosting (UserID, Wallpostings, FriendUserID) VALUES (" + friendid + ", '" + TextBox1.Text + "', " + theUserId + ")"
```

becomes

```
"INSERT INTO WallPosting (UserID, Wallpostings, FriendUserID) VALUES ('" + friendid + "', '" + TextBox1.Text + "', '" + theUserId + "')"
```

Have to qualify the strings using single quotes. otherwise they are treated as variables by the parser.

Comment: Not if the value and field are numeric, then adding those quotes will cause type mismatch error.

Comment: hmm I figured they were strings...my bad